# Debug tools that captures the process name and not the process number and also be able to save the log file

Tags: pid, debugview

Can anybody suggest a Debug tool that captures the process name and not the process number and also be able to save the log file
I have come across Trace spy but it does not save the log.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at DebugView++ at https://github.com/djeedjay/DebugViewPP/
It can do what you asked and much more :)